# Unable to Reidirect in Nginx

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nginx, server

I added a new website to my server ("thissite.online") and while i wish to redirect it to port "6000", NGINX keeps redirecting it back to port '8000'. If i turn off port 8000, its leading to a 502 (Bad Gateway). Is there anything wrong i have implemented to my code? The site is built with React and build

```
server {
    server_name admin.abc.tech www.admin.abc.tech;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
     }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.abc.tech/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.abc.tech/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name abc.tech www.abc.tech;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
     }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name thissite.online www.thissite.online;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
     }
}
server {
    if ($host = admin.abc.tech) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    listen 80;
    server_name admin.abc.tech www.admin.abc.tech;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Here is my server code: This is the code i normally use when i start a server application

```
const express = require ('express')

const app  = express()
const PORT  = process.env.PORT || 6000
const path = require('path')

require('dotenv').config()


app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));

app.use(require('./Routes/auth'))

app.use(express.static("client/build"));
  
app.get(/^\/(?!api).*/, (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html")); // relative path
  });

app.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log(`server connected http://localhost:${PORT}`);
})
```

Comment: 1. Have you tried accessing the url using Ingonito mode or another browser? I had this issue with chrome and I had to clear the cache to let him find the real route rather than the cached one

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron Even if I open it in incognito it still says the page cant be reached

Comment: Is your server accessible using localhost?

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron Yes All of it are under 1 server

Comment: Try removing all your nginx config except the isonline to help you debug

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron I did do that, in fact i stopped all the redirecting ports except 6000. That is when i got this issue where it directs me to a 502. If i were to switch on all the server ports again (5000, 6000, 8000) the port 6000 is redirected to 8000 again. Surprisingly enough port 5000 is completely alright

Comment: what's the url you are using to access your application ? Is it `http://thissite.online` or `http://localhost` ?

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh, Well it got solved on it's own.... Seems like it takes some time for the server to respond with the right DNS

Answer (score 0):

The Code is actually right, turns out it takes time for the settings to take place